# Firestore text search containing keyword Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, full-text-search

i was planning to have a full text search feature for the `String` name field of my document, but from the research i have done , it seems like searching text with firestore is not possible, then i come up with solution which is creating a new array field to store keyword in document, like this

[image]

and then i called it using arracVontains, with searchedKeyword as the inputted text from user

```
_firestore
        .collection(itemOrderPath)
        .where("keyword", arrayContains:searchedKeyword)
```

Now, i'm quite hesitant on wether it is okay to do it like this(will there be huge impact on my app)? or is there any better way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: See my response here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817849/2555999

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same position, before, I decided to go with the Full-text search using Algolia + Firestore

Few Risks with current flow:

1. More manual work needed. Create / Update
2. String data is case sensitive
3. Here you are adding more weight to your document. It may affect the performance
4. For single keyword search `array-contains` would be enough; However for multi keyword search you have to go with `array-contains-any`, but it has few limitations.
5. etc, etc

I tried the same solution that you are following now. However, due to few limitation, I picked up this `Algolia` solution. For me, this solutions seems bit costly; however at initial stage we could manage this. But at the end, you have to decide based on your application's requirement.

Solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: thankyou for answering, but im planning to use spark plan firestore first and it wont support cloud function which needed to use algolia? and the scale of my app is probably not that high would it still okay using this method?

Comment: cloud function for indexing. If you don't want it, you could still index from your app (`http` way). Algolia provides 10k free search and indexes, it would be enough for you. I prefer you to read their plans and limitations.

Comment: another one solution is elastic search, as mentioned in the firestore doc. But as you said your app usage not that much high, good to go with `Pay per Use` model with good enough free credits.

Comment: @MuthuThavamani `String data is case sensitive` you can lowercase your array before saving it. `Here you are adding more weight to your document` this is also avoidable, see my response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817849/2555999